# Twilio messagin not receiving incomming message callback

Tags: symfony, twilio, sms, api-platform.com, twilio-php

I use `Symfony 5`, `ApiPlatform` and `Twilio`

My goal is to send a message to a client, then get his answer through a webhook and store it.

So I've open my route through ngrok

`ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:{{port}}`

And setup my twilio message settings like this :

[image]

And implemented a function to send a sms :

```
        $client = new Client($sid, $authtoken);
        $client->messages->create(
            'myNumber',
            array(
                'from' => '+twilioNumber',
                'body' => $message,
                'statusCallback' => "https://a7c6f2ea3843.ngrok.io/twilio/response",
                'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST',
            )
        );
```

when I send a message, I receive a callback on this my webhook `/twilio/response` with the status `sent` and `delivered`.

But I never receive the callback w the content of the sms I sent to twilio in reponse of the one I received

Do I miss some configuration? Or am i missing something? Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check Notifier component of Symfony, I know that it supports Twilio? But not sure that it supports callbacks from it.

Comment: Also, why you using ngrok here, why not to configure some endpoint in symfony that will receive that callback?

Comment: Also, as I understand `statusCallback` attribute means that the callback will contain only status, try to not use it, - you just need configure callback in Twilio as I understand.

Comment: It looks like your webhook is setup correctly in the phone number configuration and that you can receive requests over your webhook as you are receiving the statusCallback requests. Are you definitely receiving the reply? Can you see it in your [message logs](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/sms)? Are there any errors in your [Twilio debugger logs](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who would run into this kind of problem, it was an error of configuration.

On twilio console of your number you can find a link `Modify the Messaging Service configuration` just above the webhooks

I needed to click on it and configure it to receive the incoming messages and enter the webhook I needed to recover data when one was received.

The webhook I had configured as shown above only send data to confirm that an sms had been send and received from twilio to your client.